# Rails 4 gem size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Curious why gem 'rails' started to be more than 1 MB from version 4.0.

[See the difference](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions):
4.0.0.beta1 February 26, 2013 (1.49 MB)
3.2.17 February 18, 2014 (3.5 KB)

EDIT:
As Chris Gunther found in commit history and wrote below "Commit [6d87cd02](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/6d87cd028b32570973450424db164e5405a0ee13) moved the guides from the railties gem to the rails gem."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commit [6d87cd02](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/6d87cd028b32570973450424db164e5405a0ee13) moved the guides from the `railties` gem to the `rails` gem. While the `rails` gem went up in size, the `railties` gem when down in size:

```
rails 4.0.0.beta1    1.49 MB
rails 3.2.17         3.5 KB

railties 4.0.0.beta1 110 KB
railties 3.2.17      1.52 MB
```

https://rubygems.org/gems/railties/versions